# community app not visible in app launcher on profile level

Tags: community, lightning-apps, app

[image]how to enable link to communities app on click app launcher on profile level. I'm System admin and I'm able to see it. But a custom profile of salesforce license type is unable to see it.

Comment: You have to add those profiles as member in community

Comment: great thank you @Ayub

Comment: No worries...adding as answer so that can help other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community will be visible as App only if your profile is added as member of community. Simply add desired profile as member: Setup -- communities -- workspaces -- adminstration -- member - (add your profile).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Communities Administration and add your profile as a member for the community.